# How to create/deploy a lambda function in different region from cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy a lambda function in **us-east-1** region by using a **cloudformation stack** which is in **eu-west-1** region. *I don't want to use custom resource*. So is there any way to do this using some property or except custom resource (custom resource will be my last option).

Comment: Did you find a viable solution?

Comment: No, in my case I didn't get the exact solution. So I used custom resources.

Comment: how did you resolve it using custom resources? Are you using Cloudformation to deploy your resources?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to deploy the same stack in a different region?
Or do you want to deploy a stack in another region which will be reusing some resources from another stack?

Comment: I have a stack stack which deploys several functins in eu-west-1.. now I want to deploy a function in us-east-1 from same stack by adding a resource in it..

Comment: What could work would be to use the same CloudFormation template for both stacks. 

Add a condition so that some resources are created only in eu-west-1 region.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your functions to a S3 bucket and then create a stack for each region to deploy the same function from S3 inside each region. Also you can upload the cloudformation template to a S3 bucket, then from AWS CLI deploy it in all the regions where you need the functions